# Searching Complex Nested JSON Objects in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

How can I efficiently search nested JSON objects in Elasticsearch and return only the relevant data without returning the entire document?

I have a JSON object representing a menu structure that will be ingested per user. Each menu item has nested fields such as Text, Url, Area, and Children. I would like to be able to search on any of these fields and return only the relevant data for the search query. For example, if I search for 'Workflow Roles', I would like to only return the relevant menu item and not all the extra data.

I have tried creating a nested mapping for the menu object, but my queries using inner hits return too much data. I have also experimented with path filters but have not found a satisfactory solution.

So my questions are:

1. What is the best way to ingest a deeply nested JSON object in
   Elasticsearch for efficient search?
2. How should the mapping be structured for such a deeply nested
   object?
3. How can I write a query that will allow me to search on all nested
   fields and return only the relevant data for the search query?

**Here is an example of the JSON object that needs to be searched:**

```
[
  {
    "MenuStructure": 0,
    "NavigationLinkId": 0,
    "Children": [
      {
        "MenuStructure": 0,
        "NavigationLinkId": 111,
        "Text": "Bulk Actions",
        "Action": "Index",
        "Controller": "BulkUpload",
        "Area": "Company",
        "Url": "/some-url/bulk-upload",
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "MenuStructure": 1,
    "NavigationLinkId": 1,
    "Children": [
      {
        "MenuStructure": 1,
        "NavigationLinkId": 2,
        "Text": "Company Config",
        "Area": "Company",
        "Url": "javascript:void(0);",
        "Children": [
          {
            "MenuStructure": 1,
            "NavigationLinkId": 0,
            "Text": "Basic Settings",
            "Url": "javascript:void(0);",
            "Children": [
              {
                "MenuStructure": 1,
                "NavigationLinkId": 60668,
                "Text": "Company Settings",
                "Icon": "fas fa-cogs",
                "Url": "javascript:void(0);",
                "Children": [
                  {
                    "MenuStructure": 1,
                    "NavigationLinkId": 27,
                    "Text": "Basic Company Information",
                    "Icon": "fa fa-building",
                    "Action": "Index",
                    "Controller": "CompanyProfile",
                    "Area": "Company",
                    "Url": "/some-url/company-profile",
                  },
                  {
                    "MenuStructure": 1,
                    "NavigationLinkId": 163,
                    "Text": "Reminder Contact Details",
                    "Icon": "fas fa-balance-scale-right",
                    "Url": "/some-url/classic/163",
                  }
                ]
              },
              {
                "MenuStructure": 1,
                "NavigationLinkId": 0,
                "Text": "Dropdown Management",
                "Icon": "fas fa-users-class",
                "Url": "javascript:void(0);",
                "Children": [
                  {
                    "MenuStructure": 1,
                    "NavigationLinkId": 261,
                    "Text": "Workflow Roles",
                    "Action": "Index",
                    "Controller": "CompanyWorkflowRoles",
                    "Area": "Company",
                    "Url": "/some-url/workflow-roles"
                  },
                  {
                    "MenuStructure": 1,
                    "NavigationLinkId": 50323,
                    "Text": "Other Dropdowns",
                    "Icon": "fas fa-balance-scale-right",
                    "Url": "/some-url/classic/50323"
                  }
                ]
              },
              {
                "MenuStructure": 1,
                "NavigationLinkId": 50327,
                "Text": "Legislative Configurations",
                "Icon": "fas fa-balance-scale-right",
                "Url": "javascript:void(0);",
                "Children": [
                  {
                    "MenuStructure": 1,
                    "NavigationLinkId": 244,
                    "Text": "Statistics SA Config",
                    "Url": "/some-url/classic/244"
                  }
                ]
              }
            ]
          },
          
          {
            "MenuStructure": 1,
            "NavigationLinkId": 167,
            "Text": "Security",
            "Icon": "fa fa-lock",
            "Url": "javascript:void(0);",
            "Children": [
              {
                "MenuStructure": 1,
                "NavigationLinkId": 167,
                "Text": "Security",
                "Icon": "fa fa-lock",
                "Url": "javascript:void(0);",
                "Children": [
                  {
                    "MenuStructure": 1,
                    "NavigationLinkId": 168,
                    "Text": "User Profiles",
                    "Url": "/some-url/classic/168",
                  },
                  {
                    "MenuStructure": 1,
                    "NavigationLinkId": 169,
                    "Text": "Security Roles",
                    "Url": "/some-url/classic/169",
                  },
                  {
                    "MenuStructure": 1,
                    "NavigationLinkId": 188,
                    "Text": "User Org. Unit Permissions",
                    "Url": "/some-url/classic/188",
                  },
                  {
                    "MenuStructure": 1,
                    "NavigationLinkId": 60610,
                    "Text": "Activate Users",
                    "Url": "/some-url/classic/60610",
                  }
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

**To achieve this, I have tried creating a nested field type mapping for the menu object. Here is an example mapping:**

```
PUT my-index
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "user_id": {
        "type": "keyword"
      },
      "menu": {
        "type": "nested",
        "properties": {
          "MenuStructure": {
            "type": "long"
          },
          "NavigationLinkId": {
            "type": "long"
          },
          "Text": {
            "type": "text"
          },
          "Action": {
            "type": "keyword"
          },
          "Controller": {
            "type": "keyword"
          },
          "Area": {
            "type": "keyword"
          },
          "Url": {
            "type": "keyword"
          },
          "Icon": {
            "type": "keyword"
          },
          "Children": {
            "type": "nested",
            "properties": {
              "MenuStructure": {
                "type": "long"
              },
              "NavigationLinkId": {
                "type": "long"
              },
              "Text": {
                "type": "text"
              },
              "Action": {
                "type": "keyword"
              },
              "Controller": {
                "type": "keyword"
              },
              "Area": {
                "type": "keyword"
              },
              "Url": {
                "type": "keyword"
              },
              "Icon": {
                "type": "keyword"
              },
              "Children": {
                "type": "nested",
                "properties": {
                  "MenuStructure": {
                    "type": "long"
                  },
                  "NavigationLinkId": {
                    "type": "long"
                  },
                  "Text": {
                    "type": "text"
                  },
                  "Action": {
                    "type": "keyword"
                  },
                  "Controller": {
                    "type": "keyword"
                  },
                  "Area": {
                    "type": "keyword"
                  },
                  "Url": {
                    "type": "keyword"
                  },
                  "Icon": {
                    "type": "keyword"
                  },
                  "Children": {
                    "type": "nested",
                    "properties": {
                      "MenuStructure": {
                        "type": "long"
                      },
                      "NavigationLinkId": {
                        "type": "long"
                      },
                      "Text": {
                        "type": "text"
                      },
                      "Action": {
                        "type": "keyword"
                      },
                      "Controller": {
                        "type": "keyword"
                      },
                      "Area": {
                        "type": "keyword"
                      },
                      "Url": {
                        "type": "keyword"
                      },
                      "Icon": {
                        "type": "keyword"
                      },
                      "Children": {
                        "type": "nested",
                        "properties": {
                          "MenuStructure": {
                            "type": "long"
                          },
                          "NavigationLinkId": {
                            "type": "long"
                          },
                          "Text": {
                            "type": "text"
                          },
                          "Action": {
                            "type": "keyword"
                          },
                          "Controller": {
                            "type": "keyword"
                          },
                          "Area": {
                            "type": "keyword"
                          },
                          "Url": {
                            "type": "keyword"
                          },
                          "Icon": {
                            "type": "keyword"
                          }
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**How can I search for any of the children's nested properties, I tried the below and some other similar types of queries:**

```
GET my-index/_search
{
  "query": {   
    "nested": {
      "path": "menu",
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {"match": 
            {
              "menu.Children.Area": "Company"
            }
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      "inner_hits": {"highlight": {"fields": {"menu.Children.Area": {}}}}
    }
  }
}
```

the above query does not really work as its basically returning so much data. I only want to return the inner hits, for instance if you search for 'Workflow Roles' only return

```
{
    "MenuStructure": 1,
    "NavigationLinkId": 261,
    "Text": "Workflow Roles",
    "Action": "Index",
    "Controller": "CompanyWorkflowRoles",
    "Area": "Company",
    "Url": "/some-url/workflow-roles"
}
```

not all the extra data. I have tried quite a few combination with path_filters etc. But I think I am going down the path.

Comment: You need multiple levels of nested fields (`menu` + all `Children` sub-fields) and design your query accordingly, then it will work as you expect

Comment: Hi Val, i updated my mappings is that what you meant?

Comment: Exactly and with that type of mapping you're able to retrieve only the nested elements that make sense using inner_hits

Comment: awesome, one more question, if i do write the query now, how would you structure the match statement, because there are multiple children now. do i need to match on all of them like "menu.Children.Children.Children.Children.Text": "Company" and one level back
"menu.Children.Children.Children.Text": "Company" and so on. Seems a bit strange todo it like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need multiple levels of nested fields (`menu` + all `Children` sub-fields) and design your query accordingly, then it will work as you expect.

The query will need to be designed in a way that each nested field needs its own nested query, so you'd probably have to do something like this:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "minimum_should_match": 1, 
      "should": [
        {
          "nested": {
            "path": "menu",
            "query": {
              "match": {
                "menu.Text": "Company"
              }
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "nested": {
            "path": "menu.Children",
            "query": {
              "match": {
                "menu.Children.Text": "Company"
              }
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "nested": {
            "path": "menu.Children.Children",
            "query": {
              "match": {
                "menu.Children.Children.Text": "Company"
              }
            }
          }
        },
        ...
      ]
    }
  }
}
```